# do i need to pay facebook if I want to use facebook login for my app?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to develop an app, in which I am planning to keep an option as "Login through facebook".
So do I need to pay for that to facebook?

Comment: No, you don't have to.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question

Answer (score 1):

It is free.
 check out [THIS LINK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login)
Instructions are included.